# bottle route add css file

Tags: html, css, bottle

I have a test function that looks like this:

```
@route('/name/')
@route('/name/<something>')
# argument passed and two routes
def name(something="nothing written"):
    print 'arg:',something
    return template('resp',something=something)
```

template resp.tpl:

```
%rebase('base.tpl',something=something)

<p>you wrote {{something}}</p>
```

template base.tpl

```
...
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
% if defined('base'):
<p>base.tpl overriden</p>
{{!base}}
% else:
<p>base not overriden</p>
% end
```

and my static file function:

```
@route('<filename:re:.*\.css>')
def css(filename):
print "css:",filename
return static_file(filename,root='./static/css',mimetype='text/css')
```

but when testing in firefox with 'http://localhost:8080/name/jonas' I get this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2015 11:25:00] "GET /name/jonas HTTP/1.1" 200 1334
   arg: bootstrap.min.css
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2015 11:25:00] "GET /name/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1"  200 1346
   arg: bootstrap.min.js
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2015 11:25:00] "GET /name/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1345
```

the problem is that my function tries to load my css as a second argument after the first call and that css is actually not loaded. I've looked all over the docs but I cannnot find a solution. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to serve your css file from /name/ directory. But there's nothing to serve. Solution :

1.Name your route wich serving css file

```
@route('<filename:re:.*\.css>', name='static')
```

2.Render your template with `get_url` function

```
%rebase('base.tpl',something=something, get_url=bottle.Bottle().get_url)
```

3.Call it in your template

```
<link href="{{ get_url(routename='static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: I tried that solution but got this error message: 

RouteBuildError: ('No route with that name.', 'static')

Also, I had to import Bottle into my template: 
    % from bottle import Bottle
    <link href={{Bottle().get_url(routename='static',filename='bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
othervise it doesen't recognize get_url.

Comment: sorry for the mess, my response should be below your answer

Comment: try to separate your static files like css, imgaes from project root. And you do not need to import Bootle class in your template. You can define any function in your template like this `bottle.SimpleTemplate['defaults'] = your_function` and call it in your template

Comment: ok, saw this now. the solution I posted works but the import of bottle for the url function in the templates is a bit clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it works now with this setup:

base.tpl:

```
% from bottle import url
...

<link href="{{url('static',filename='bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

resp.tpl:

```
% from bottle import url
%rebase('base.tpl',something=something,url=url('static',filename='bootstrap.min.css'))
<p>you wrote {{something}}</p>
```

webtest.py

```
@route('<filename:re:.*\.css>',name='static')
    def css(filename):
    print "css:",filename
    return static_file(filename,root='./static/css',mimetype='text/css')
```

the key thing here is that bottle has to be imported for both template functions. I would be good if that could be avoided somehow.